# jquery and prototype conflicts

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, lightbox

I know this question has been asked many times, and I've searched stackoverflow and google for answers but none of them worked for me, so maybe my errors are caused in different areas, anyways here is my javascript includes

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js\"></script>\n";

echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"javascript/watermark.min.js\"></script>\n";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"javascript/jquery.cycle.js\"></script>\n";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js\"></script>\n";

echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"javascript/prototype.js\"></script>\n";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"javascript/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder.js\"></script>\n";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"javascript/lightbox.js\"></script>\n";

echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"javascript/jquery.userdrive.js\"></script>\n";
```

whenever I put prototype.js, scriptaculous.js and lightbox.js after jQuery library, my userdrive doesn't work, and when I put it before, it works but not completely. I know there is a conflict between the $ signs but I don't know how to fix this. Also, my userdrive includes ajax calls and code for sortable grid.

Comment: Checkout: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ should have what you're looking for. Also be careful when including different libraries that override base prototypes as they may cause incompatibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your userdrive.js are using the global variable "$" without a closure it will fail because the prototype.js remove the link between "$" and "jQuery"

**This is a clousure:**

```
(function($){
  ...
})(jQuery)
```

Try put your userdrive into a closure and uses the noConflict method to prevent other errors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Comment: so put my everything in userdrive in (function($){
  ...
})(jQuery)
? instead of $(document).ready(function() {...});

Answer (score 2):

Use the noConflict capability:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Make sure that you include the jQuery library BEFORE this code, here's a doc on it:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: so I should include jquery, the noConflict() and then other libraries?